# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.IDataReader' to 'System.Data.IDataAdapter'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#

My code is..

```
    public IDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string commandText, IDbConnection con)
    {
        return ExecuteDataReader(commandText, con, CommandType.Text);
    }
    public IDataAdapter ExecuteDataReader(string commandText)
    {
        IDbConnection connection = _connectionManager.GetConnection();
        return ExecuteDataReader(commandText, connection);   **//error shows**
    }
```

How to fix this issue? Help me.

ERROR:

> *Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.IDataReader' to
>   'System.Data.IDataAdapter'. An explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the simplest approach is just to change the return type of the method:

```
public IDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string commandText)
```

If you *really* want to return an `IDataAdapter`, you'll need to work out how to implement `IDataAdapter` from an `IDataReader`. But they're really significantly different interfaces - it seems unlikely that you want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You method returns a `DataAdapter`, however your return statement is returning a `IDataReader`:

Change the return type, if you wish to return a `IDataReader`:

```
public IDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string commandText)
{
    IDbConnection connection = _connectionManager.GetConnection();
    return ExecuteDataReader(commandText, connection);   **//error shows**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the return type of second method to `IDataReader`

```
 public IDataReader ExecuteDataReader(string commandText)
{
    IDbConnection connection = _connectionManager.GetConnection();
    return ExecuteDataReader(commandText, connection);   **//error shows**
}
```